# how to stop socket looping on my node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, server

So my friends are looping this:

```js
$(function() {
    const socket = io.connect();
});
```

This causes thousands of socket connections. How can I stop this?

Comment: Track connected clients and limit the number of connections per client?

Comment: You should be able to block an incoming socket connection if the client already has one. You could use things such as IP address, login profile, or perhaps their MAC address (this can be spoofed). Personally I'd use their auth.